# Link to show Google reviews

Tags: html, google-maps, google-my-business-api

Currently working with a website and Google MyBusiness. Rather than duplicate content, we want to include a URL to the reviews from customers on Google MyBusiness (Google Maps) -does anyone have any ideas on the format of the URL?

There's lots of information available on how to make links to encourage customers to write reviews
    `https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=<place_id>`
but I've found nothing about a link to display reviews.

Answer (score 4):

https://search.google.com/local/reviews?placeid= is accurate; you can also search for your business on Google; hit the read reviews link and when the javascript modal pops up with the reviews copy the URL; for example:

I googled 'Sushi Mikasa' a local Sushi restaurant; they have 40 reviews, I click on the 40 Reviews link to read them and the reviews modal list pops up; the URL on my browser is: https://www.google.com/search?ei=O5wPXcbfPIbH_QbZ2azYDA&q=sushi+mikasa&oq=sushi+mikasa&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i20i263j0l4j0i22i30l3.7626.12192..12313...0.0..0.89.1197.16......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i67j0i131j0i131i67j0i131i10j0i131i20i263.rbNKWeU3HEo#lrd=0x89c2448abab82c39:0x7eae8848db443229,1,,,

This URL will take a user straight to the review box; similar to how the local/reviews/placeid= does; except this uses a search string instead of a Place ID. Regardless, you've found two great solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

Think I've now cracked it with a bit of trial and error:
`https://search.google.com/local/reviews?placeid=<place_id>` seems to work.

Comment: It seems that you should accept the other answer, since it mentioned the solution you ended up finding?

Answer (score 0):

One additional trick (without finding the placeid) is to click `Share` then select `Embed a map` tab. It should display the place details in a small white box in top left corner with a `X Reviews` hyperlink, just copy that. Example for a place **aesthetic dental centre**:

[image]

The link is https://search.google.com/local/reviews?placeid=ChIJlxoV2VxmXj4RSaoikrizWGg&q=Aesthetic+Dental+Center&hl=en&gl=IN
which directly opens the place reviews. Quick and simple :)